# I can't change permalink in Wordpress 4.5.3

Tags: plugins, troubleshooting

I have trouble with my site.
I use latest version of Wordpress, but when I try to change post permalink then I haven't any result.
Change link dialog isn't showing.
Simply nothing happens :( No errors, no alerts, nothing.

Console doesn't have any errors too.

This site have installed the following plugins:

Active Custom Forms
qTranslate
TinyMCE Advanced
User Role Editor

I can deactivated them, but it isn't any effect.

In wp-config.php not exist WP-HOME and WP-SITEURL, I have read about this problem.

Comment: I have solved my problem - change permalink not work because I have installed plugin qTranslate.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, if you don't have enabled a custom permalink format in `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`you can't edit your permalink in the post editor.

Try first to Choose another option than `/?p=123` in Options > Permalinks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this option is enabled. I have tried to change and resave this settings, but is has not any effect.